# How to Mock a Declarative Client in Micronaut?

Tags: client, httpclient, micronaut, micronaut-rest, micronaut-test

I have Class in which I call a method from a declarative client. But for my test I don't want it to call the actual URL. Instead I want to Mock it. How can I do that as it is not a class but an Interface annotated with @Client?

Example code:- [here](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-http-client-gradle-java.html). Please check section 4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your test you can replace the http client bean with a mock. Please find a Spock snippet below.

```
// replace the client with a mock
@MockBean(YourClientInterface)
YourClientInterface yourClientInterface() {
    return Mock(YourClientInterface)
}

// inject the mock in order to configure responses when it gets called
@Inject
YourClientInterface client
```

Now you can write tests and your code will run against the mock instead of the actual http client.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore in Micronaut 2.x